# Best practices for Setting VSTS agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Our shop is transitioning from an TFS 2008 server to VSTS. I've been tasked with setting up a server to download and configure agents. There is a lot of MS's documentation online which I am reviewing--however, a brief practical document outlining what exactly is needed would be helpful. For example, should I create a service account for these agents to run under? If so, what sort of Windows permissions are appropriate? Can any of you direct me to such a reference guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, VSTS provides a script to setup agents. You need to check in your agent queues, and there should be a setup script in there that you can copy/paste on your build machines.

[image]

If you're deploying release agents, they must run with a user that has enough permissions to manage a release (i.e execute sql scripts, manage IIS sites, ...). There should also be a setup script in there that you can copy/paste on your release machines.

[image]

For build agents, they can run with the default identity, as they usually do not access resources of the machines; they only need to modify their sandbox environments. However, if your builds include integration tests and other steps that are environment-bound, you should provide a custom identity that has the required permissions.

Comment: Thank you sturcotte06.  Basically I'll be setting up release agents; specifically to deploy sql dacpacs. I am considering a concept of a uniform agent (active directory domain) account for this server that would have the permissions required to manage a release. At the moment, I am struggling with determining which Windows permissions are involved in making that possible ! :)

Comment: Isn't it only SQL Server permissions? It might have to be able to execute powershell (depending on the implementation of the SQL Server deployment task in VSTS).

Comment: Yes, I think that's where we at now, sturcotte06. We will definitely need to sort out SQL Server permissions.